# Null reference error when accessing an array

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyArrObj[] arrOfObj; //Array of objects
}
```

When I try to access it using:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass;
myClass.arrOfObj = GetData();
```

it gives me a null exception. If it wasn't an array, I could have new'd it, but i am not sure how to handle this.

Comment: Show the stack trace.  Are you *sure* the NRE is not in the implementation of `GetData`?

Comment: Also show us what GetData does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 2):

When creating an array of a reference type (`MyArrObj` in your case), it is required that you allocate memory for each array element (using `new` operator) in addition to allocating memory for the array itself.
**Array of Reference types**
For example, if you create an MyArrObj array,

```
MyArrObj[] objectArray = new MyArrObj[3];
```

Then the array elements `objectArray[0]` to `objectArray[2]` would still be `null`. A separate initialization is required.

```
objectArray[0] = new MyArrObj();
```

Only when the above step is done can you access the members of the array element.

```
objectArray[0].SomeMethod();
```

```
SomePropertyType readProperty = objectArray[0].SomeProperty;
```

If you skip the array element initialization then trying to access a member of the array element would give a `System.NullReferenceException`

```
objectArray[0].SomeMethod(); // throws NullReferenceException
```

because
`objectArray[0];`  is `null`. 
You can check this using

```
if(objectArray[0] == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("objectArray[0] is null");
}
```

---

**Array of Value types**
If you know the array before hand, then you can use the initialization pointed out by @clonked. 

 
For value types like built in types(like  `int, float`, structs, etc. you need not initialize each array element.
For example, if you create an int array,

```
int[] intArray = new int[3];
```

Then the array elements `intArray[0]` to `intArray[2]` have the memoery allocated and values can be assigned to them.

```
intArray [0] = 1;
```

---

**Check your GetData()**
So your `GetData()` method should include code like this,

```
private MyArrObj[] GetData()
{
    int numberOfObjects = GetNumberOfObjects(); // Get the number of objects at runtime

    MyArrObj[] objectArray = new MyArrObj[numberOfObjects];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        objectArray[i] = new MyArrObj();
    }

    return objectArray;
}
```

**More information**

- [Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx)
- [Value Types (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The way your are using your `GetData()` method, it has to return an array.

Here's a couple of ways to create an array on the fly (you'll still need to populate them, though):

```
int[] x = new int[5] ; // create a 5-element  array of integers
int[] y = (int[]) Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int),5) ; // create a 5 element array of integers
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.arrOfObj = GetData();
            foreach (var item in myClass.arrOfObj)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static int[] GetData()
    {
        return new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int[] arrOfObj; //Array of objects
}
```

the GetData method is the important part.
it has to initialize a new array and return it.

Answer (score 0):

If the signature of your `GetData()` method looks like `public MyArrObj[] GetData()` then your code should work correctly.  I tested your code with 2 versions of the 'GetData' method:

```
public MyArrObj[] GetData()
{
    return new MyArrObj[3] { new MyArrObj(), new MyArrObj(), new MyArrObj() };
}

public MyArrObj[] GetData2()
{
    return new MyArrObj[0];
}
```

Neither of these methods threw a null reference exception.  I would suspect there is something else inside of your `GetData()` method that is throwing the null reference, rather than the operation of assigning the results of that method to the `arrOfObj` field.